# Explain this proof on proving the basic integral property

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-explanation

Title says it, the beginning of this proof in my textbook doesn't make sense.

---

**Theorem $\mathbf{7.4.1}$**. *Assume $f:[a,b] \to \mathbf{R}$ is bounded, and let $c \in (a,b)$. Then, $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if $f$ is integrable on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$. In this case we have*
$$\int_{a}^{b}{f} =\int_{a}^{c}{f}+\int_{c}^{b}{f}. $$
*Proof.* If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. then for $\epsilon>0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon$. Because refining a partition can only potentitally bring the upper and lower sums closer together, we can simply add $c$ to $P$ if it is not already there. Then, let $P_1= P\cap [a,c]$ be a partition of $[a,c]$ and $P_2 = P\cap[c,b]$ be a partition of $[c,b]$. It follows that
$$U(f,P_1)-L(f,P_1) < \epsilon\quad \text{ and }\quad U(f,P_2)-L(f,P_2) < \epsilon,$$
implying that $f$ is integrable on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$.

$\dots$

---

What I don't get is that second last line. i.e. The fact that the upper and lower sums of each of the two partitions are really within $\epsilon$ within each other. Why must this be the case? I understand that $P$ was chosen such that its upper and lower sums would have been $\epsilon$ away from each other. All I am comfortable in saying right now is that
$$U(f,P_1)+U(f,P_2)-L(f,P_1)-L(f,P_2)< \epsilon.$$In the converse direction of proof (not shown here), the author starts with $P_1$ and $P_2$ as shown above, and ensures their upper and lower sums are indeed within $\epsilon/2$ of each other, and then adds the two equations to get a similar inequality for $P$. Now that part made sense, but going the forward way did not.

Comment: If sum of two non-negative numbers is less than $\epsilon$ then each of them  is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: how did I miss that darn. well thanks for pointing it out!